# System.StringException: Invalid id: ["0011H000023s57sQAA"]

Tags: apex, json

Trying to insert a record with string parameters, but facing an issue with string exception

*Logs show out for debug logs:*

DEBUG|@@@@:::String 1:::TESTING 3

DEBUG|@@@@:::String 2:::["0011H000023s57sQAA"]

```
@AuraEnabled

public static string insertRcd(String str1,String str2)
 {

    System.debug('@@@@:::String 1:::'+str1);

    System.debug('@@@@:::String 2:::'+str2); // record Id of Account - using JSON.stringify value is passed.

    BM_Suite__c obj = new BM_Suite__c();

        obj.Name = str1;         

        obj.Customer__c = Id.valueOf(str2);

        insert obj;

    return obj.id;         

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str2` is not the string representation of an Id.

> ["0011H000023s57sQAA"]

It looks like this is the string representation of a one-length *string array* containing an Id.

Your JavaScript controller is sending the data incorrectly; you shouldn't need to `stringify()` an Id value. Instead, just access the first element of the array on the client-side controller, and pass that element directly to your Apex server call.

Comment: That is correct, from an array I selected a value. But how to access it in client side. @api selectedvalue = event.deatil; // passing this as parameter with stringify()

Comment: Get the first value (presumably) from the array, and send that to Apex.

Comment: Can you provide an example how to use in Client side ? based on @api selectedvalue

Comment: An example of what? You just need to access an array element.

Comment: YES in client side.

Comment: If you need to learn core JavaScript syntax, the Mozilla Developer Network is the place to go. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

In your code, str seems to be [“0011H000023s57sQAA”]. Remove the brackets. You might be sending a list of Ids from your component.

Comment: I m selecting a record from list of values, it is maintains same format in JS. Can I get a solution on it.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your scenario. @Akash

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could get assign value be deserialize the incoming value.

List lst = (List) System.JSON.deserialize(str2, List.class);

obj.Customer__c = lst[0];